# Using JSON to implement User Defined Fields for a Document Management System

Tags: python, mysql, django

We are developing a document management system. The user approaches our system and creates his own document. So, there is a need to implement custom fields i.e, user-defined-fields. Basically, each document has different fields with different datatypes.

Is using JSON Field in mysql the best way to implement this? If so, how? Else, what would you suggest?

I  am looking for performance.

Comment: why not mongodb?

Comment: For postgresql i usually define a type class with a json field that stores a JSONSchema, and then a docs table with a json field that is expected to conform to that schema.

Comment: Fields do not have performance. *Queries* have performance. You can't pick the right DBMS or data structures until you know which queries you want to optimize for.